# StackNavigator this.props.navigation cached

Tags: react-native

I am using a FlatList and within it I am doing:

```
let pressed = () => {
      this.props.navigation.navigate('DetailScreen', {item: item});
    }
```

then in render() on the DetailScreen I am doing: `this.props.navigation.getParam('item', null)`

so the first item I click on in the list, shows the correct item in the DetailScreen, but then if I go back and click on any other item then this.props.navigation.getParam('item', null) always returns the same item. Its like it does not get changed after the first select.

List.js

```
_renderRow({item}){
    let pressed = () => {
      this.props.navigation.navigate('Details', {item: item});
    }

    let actualRowComponent =
      <View style={css.list.row}>
        <View style={css.list.rowContainer}>

          <Text style={css.list.rowSymbol}>{item.sym}</Text>
          <Text style={css.list.rowTitle}>{item.title}</Text>
        </View>
        <Button title={"$"+item.amount}
          onPress={pressed}
          backgroundColor='#EE7600'
          buttonStyle={{borderRadius: 5}}
          />
      </View>;


    let touchableWrapperIos =
      <TouchableHighlight
        activeOpacity={0.5}
        underlayColor="#fff"
        onPress={pressed}
      >
        {actualRowComponent}
      </TouchableHighlight>;


    let touchableWrapperAndroid =
      <TouchableNativeFeedback
        useForeground={true}
        background={TouchableNativeFeedback.SelectableBackgroundBorderless()}
        onPress={pressed}
      >
        {actualRowComponent}
      </TouchableNativeFeedback>;

    if (require('react-native').Platform.OS === 'ios') {
      return touchableWrapperIos;
    }
    else return touchableWrapperAndroid;
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <View style={css.baseStyles.baseContainer}>
        <View style={{justifyContent: 'center',alignItems: 'center', marginBottom: 40, marginTop: 50}}>

        </View>
        <SectionWidget title="Items" >
          <FlatList
            style={css.baseStyles.flatListContainer}
            data={this.items}
            renderItem={this._renderRow}
            keyExtractor={(item,index) => item.id.toString()}
          />
        </SectionWidget>

      </View>
    );
  }
```

Detail.js

```
render(){
    const item = this.props.navigation.getParam('item', null);
    console.log(item.title)

    return (
      <View style={css.baseStyles.container}>
        <ScrollView>
          <View style={{marginTop: 40, marginBottom: 60, flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center',alignItems: 'center'}}>
               <Text style={css.baseStyles.priceText}>${item.amount}</Text>
               <Text style={css.baseStyles.subText}> +$0.50 </Text>
          </View>
          <Divider style={{ backgroundColor: '#ccc', marginLeft: 10, marginRight: 10  }} />
          <View style={{marginTop: 60, marginBottom: 30, flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center',alignItems: 'center'}}>
               <Text style={css.baseStyles.titleText}>{item.title}</Text>

               <Text style={css.baseStyles.descriptionText}>{item.summary}</Text>
          </View>
          <Divider style={{ backgroundColor: '#ccc', marginLeft: 10, marginRight: 10 }} />
        </ScrollView>
        <View style={css.baseStyles.footerContainer}>
          <Button title='Buy'
                backgroundColor='#EE7600'
                buttonStyle={{marginTop: 20, marginBottom: 20, borderRadius: 5, width: 150}}

                />
        </View>

      </View>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Can you post more from your code? I mean at least Flatlist

Comment: Thanks @Milore, updated.

Comment: Have you tried to extract that `pressed` function out of _renderRow and to pass it the whole item? I mean
`pressed = ( item ) => {
  this.props.navigation.navigate( 'Details', { item });
}`
and then call it like
`onPress={() => this.pressed( item )}`

Comment: Yes that is how I had it initially, but then thought maybe there was an issue so I moved it within the _renderRow.

Comment: @Milore the other thing I forgot to mention is that I did put a console.log in the pressed method and it is passing the correct item, it is just when I retrieve that item in the Detail.js page is it only the first item that was ever pressed. Its almost as if the first time it gets set, then never gets updated after that.

Answer (score 0):

Since I've never used React Navigation before, I was misunderstanding its usage. In fact your problem seems a logic/usage one, which has a simple solution. Your intention is to have multiple Detail screen (I mean just a component, but multiple screen in the stack), not just one with different params. This makes a BIG difference! React Navigation provides an alternative method to `navigation.navigate()`, which is `navigation.push()`, that adds a stack to the 'history' of navigation and seems to be exactly what you're looking for.
So, what you have to do is to replace

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('Details', {item: item});
```

with

```
this.props.navigation.push('Details', {item: item});
```

You can read more (and better explained) about this on the official [doc](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating.html#navigate-to-a-route-multiple-times).

Let me know if this fits with your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but it does not seem to change anything.

Comment: Uhm... When I have more time I'll try to implement a snack and I'll see. I'm sorry but at the moment I have no suggestions to try with :(

Comment: What's interesting is: static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => ({
    title: `${navigation.state.params.item.title}`,
    headerLeft: NavIcons.closeButton(navigation.goBack)
  }); shows the correct title, but within render it does not get the new item

Answer (score 0):

The issue I found was due to @autobind. If you use @autobind along with react-navigation, you will run into problems. So I removed @autobind and everything is working as expected.